# So i have a 2in1 Laptop, is there anyway i can get it to have tablet mode as well as desktop mode?

Tags: xubuntu, tablet

I was wondering if i can make my 2in1 laptop that has ubuntu 14.04 to be like windows 10 or windows 8.1 and also have desktop mode and tablet mode.

Comment: is there a way for ubuntu to recognise when i flip laptop into  the physical tablet form like windows 10 can? sometimes the keyboard keys will be pressed and same with the trackpad.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you want but it is still in development, there is a project called `Ubuntu Desktop Next` and is the `next gen` touch interface based on Unity (version 8).

Please note that this is only for Ubuntu 15.10 and it is not yet complete (there was a 15.04 build but it is gone ?), so no support here (until it is released fully next week) and potential bugs.

[You can download an .iso to try here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-desktop-next/daily-live/current/)

[See a video of `next` here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1LO6hjvSPc)

[image]

[image]

Strangely I could not find any docs for `next`, but here are [the display server docs (Mir)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mir/Spec)

I guess this would be like a tablet mode, a bit like Windows.